# Is it possible to send a header from a PHP file, that does absolutely nothing

Tags: php, request-headers

On a page where I offer music sample downloads, I have several `<a>` tags whose href points to a PHP file. Various data included as GET vars allow the proper file to be downloaded. Normally the PHP will respond with typical download headers followed by a readfile(). (the code for that is below, FYI). This results in a clean download (or download / play dialog box on some browsers). By "clean", I mean the download is completed with no disturbance in the visitors page.

However, in the unlikely event that the requested file is unavailable, I don't know what to do. I know it should not happen, but if it does I would like the download link to simply do NOTHING. Unfortunately since it is an `<a>` tag referencing a PHP file, doing nothing results in the browser clearing the page, with the URL of the PHP file in the address bar. Not a good visitor experience! So I'd like way to avoid disturbing the page and doing NOTHING if there is is an errant request. I'll use javascript to alert the visitor about what went wrong, but I can't have the errant file request clear the page!

I thought I'd had a solution by issuing a  header('Location: #'); when the script detected an impossible file download. But after a few seconds the browser cleared the page and put up a message indicating the page  "redirected you too many times." (indeed, my script log fills up with over 100 entries, even though i only clicked the  tag once.)

So far the only solution I have that works (works in the sense of NOT disturbing the visitors page if an "unavailable" file is requested)  is to point my download headers at a "dummy" file. An actual "silence.mp3" or "nosong.mp3" file. But is there a way to call a header() that does nothing to the calling page? Simply calling exit or exit() won't work (the visitor page is redirected a blank.)

Not that it matters, but this is the code I normally call in response to the d/l request...

```
function downloadFile($path) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]); // don't need this.
    $fsize =fileExists($path);
    if ($fsize == 0) 
        {
         header('Location: #'); // this doesn't work!!! (too many redirectcts)
         exit;
         }

    //$dlname = $path_parts['filename'] . "." . strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);


    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"" . $path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/x-file-to-save");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    if($fsize) header("Content-length: $fsize");
    $bytesRead = readfile($path);
    return $bytesRead;
    }
```

Comment: Why not you put target="_blank" in your a tag it will open the a new tab and file will be downloaded in that tab and if it will fail it will not disturb your main page.

Comment: @muasif80 -- As described, nothing changes on the visitor page... no new tab, no page change. Just a dialog box asking whether they want to save or "play" the file. I like that!

Comment: @fyrye. The request is being handled by the PHP script pointed to by the "href=" in the <a> tag. The header's shown do all the work. the question is what to do if I have no file to send. I don't know what you mean by what "HTTP version". there is no such header or reference in my code. So are you suggesting that in the event I have no file to send, I issue a header("HTTP/1.1  202")? I don't know the syntax and I'm no expert on headers. Let me know and I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks. Getting late here but I'll try it, let you know, and will certainly mark your answer 'accepted" if it works. It certainly will be much cleaner than forcing a download of "silence". Though I've thought that the only way it MIGHT happen will be someone with no authorization trying to use my script to get to the music. In that case, it might be fun and devious to let them download a music file containing ME speaking some condescending "words" bashing their piracy attempt! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using HTTP/1.x with a standard anchor tag, without JavaScript or other client-side interception. An `HTTP/1.0 204 No Content` status header will cause the user-agent to simply seem like nothing happened when clicking a link that returns a 204 status header.

> *HTTP/1.0 204 No Content*
>   The server has fulfilled the request but there is no new information
>   to send back. **If the client is a user agent, it should not change its**
>   **document view from that which caused the request to be generated**. This
>   response is primarily intended to allow input for scripts or other
>   actions to take place **without causing a change to the user agent's**
>   **active document view.** The response may include new metainformation in
>   the form of entity headers, which should apply to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>   Source: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Code204

This is also compatible with the `HTTP/1.1` protocol.

I recommend using output buffering to ensure no other content is being sent by your application by mistake. Additionally there should be no need to send a `Content-Length` header.

```
function downloadFile($path) {
    if (!is_file($path) || !($fsize = filesize($path))) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 204 No Content');
        exit;
    }
    $path_parts = pathinfo($path);
    header('Cache-Control: public');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $path_parts['basename'] . '"');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-file-to-save');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-length: ' . $fsize); //fsize already validated above.

    return readfile($path);
}
```

Comment: Well despite my earlier comment, i could not resist plugging this in to the code, and forcing it be the code path. I've only tried it on chrome and FF so far, and I'll not be too bent out of shape if it gives me grief on IE 8 (as far back as i support). Thanks a million! BTW, I researched heavily about headers in PHP before posting here. headers remain mysterious to me because with every turn, I learn something new I'd not seen anywhere. So this may be an impossible question, but can you recommend any reasonably complete tutorial that really explains 90% or more of the possibilities?

Comment: Oh and yes... I used to not bother with the "Content-length" header and I've never seen a failed download from leaving it out. I think I have a few other headers there in the "not critical" category. But I guess its in the "can't hurt" department. :-)

Comment: Headers for all intents and purposes are simply instructions for the user agent, on how to handle the "response".  They are a part of the [HTTP specifications](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html), so that would be where I suggest researching. You will need to think of headers as a protocol, more so than as a programming language. In that the two are treated very much so differently and as such protocols are very loose. Relying heavily on the user-agent to accept the instructions. I use MDN to determine compatibility.

Comment: @Randy Using the `Content-Length` header has been known to cause issues with corrupted file downloads, due to extra data being included in the content that is not properly accounted for within the app code. It is interpreted by some user-agents as a cut-off point or maximum amount allowed, as opposed to a suggested expected file size. Typically the web server service (Apache, IIS, NGINX) will correctly communicate the Content-Length from the generated response before sending it to the client, so it becomes redundant in "most" environments.

Comment: Another note of thanks. (Would have sent a PM but no contact info.) This has been an excellent "connect the dots" moment. I'm familiar with the diff. between language and protocols, having done a ton of low level communication drivers in C. But my web coding has been HTML->CSS->Javascript->PHP (in that order). Lately I'm doing much more in PHP, often called from <a> links or XMLHttpRequests. So now that I'm working more with the actual interaction between scripts and browsers, it finally dawns on me from this answer, that reading the actual protocol specs might be a good idea! LOL!

Answer (score 1):

**Performing the file checks before creating the links is the simplest way to do this.**

If I understand your request correctly you have files that you wish to allow a client to download, and links to PHP scripts that download certain files.

The problem with your implementation is that when the file is empty, the PHP script still must load and change the content of the clients page(from the action of loading the script), which is the **incorrect behavior** (correct being no action at all).

Since you are using  tags on the main download page, **really the only way to not change the content of the page in the case of a missing file is to compute the content of the  tags in advance**. With a simple PHP function you could check the contents of a list of files and their directories, and then generate links for the ones that exist, and blank links for the ones that do not.

**Overall, I think separating the functionality of checking whether a file exists and actually downloading the file to a client is the only way to allow the functionality you desire.**

Comment: Ofteh when I do something like this in an "onclick" event, I can do multiple XMLHttpRequests() separately, to ensure the file first. Indeed, a lot of authentication like that goes on in my case too, before a button image (in the <a> tag) is even displayed for the music in question. In addition the PHP vars passed include a pre-verified index to an array of known songs available. So what I'm asking may be overkill, because the file being unavailable should never happen. I'm just being a careful coder. Even though there's "no way' the file couldn't be there, I feel I should have a safe exit.\